# Fetch and parse multiple arrays from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm making a collection of all the movies I've watched and I keep all my data in movies.json. In movies.json there are multiple arrays, the first one being "MarvelMovies" with 2 movies in.

Next is "ComedyMovies" with also 4 movies.

I can console.log all the arrays, but I haven't figured out how to console.log each array (console.log the MarvelMovies array and ComedyMovies separately).

movies.json:

```
{
    "MarvelMovies": [{
            "Title": "The Avengers",
            "Year": "2012",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Ratings": [{
                "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
                "Value": "8.0/10"
            }, {
                "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
                "Value": "91%"
            }, {
                "Source": "Metacritic",
                "Value": "69/100"
            }],
            "Metascore": "69"

            
        }, {


            "Title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
            "Year": "2015",
            "Rated": "PG-13",
            "Released": "01 May 2015",
            "Runtime": "141 min",
            "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
            "Director": "Joss Whedon",
            "Writer": "Joss Whedon, Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Jack Kirby (based on the Marvel comics by), Joe Simon (character created by: Captain America), Jack Kirby (character created by: Captain America), Jim Starlin (character created by: Thanos)",
            "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Evans",
            "Plot": "When Tony Stark and Bruce Banner try to jump-start a dormant peacekeeping program called Ultron, things go horribly wrong and it's up to Earth's mightiest heroes to stop the villainous Ultron from enacting his terrible plan.",
            "Language": "English, Korean",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Awards": "8 wins & 49 nominations.",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM4OGJmNWMtOTM4Ni00NTE3LTg3MDItZmQxYjc4N2JhNmUxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgzMDMzMTg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Ratings": [{
                "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
                "Value": "7.3/10"
            }, {
                "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
                "Value": "75%"
            }, {
                "Source": "Metacritic",
                "Value": "66/100"
            }],
            "Metascore": "66",
            "imdbRating": "7.3",
            "imdbVotes": "759,059",
            "imdbID": "tt2395427",
            "Type": "movie",
            "DVD": "08 Sep 2015",
            "BoxOffice": "$459,005,868",
            "Production": "Marvel Studios",
            "Website": "N/A",
            "Response": "True"
        }


    ],
    "ComedyMovies": [{
            "Title": "The Avengers",
            "Year": "2012",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Ratings": [{
                "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
                "Value": "8.0/10"
            }, {
                "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
                "Value": "91%"
            }, {
                "Source": "Metacritic",
                "Value": "69/100"
            }],
            "Metascore": "69"

            
        }, {


            "Title": "Avengers: Age of Ultron",
            "Year": "2015",
            "Rated": "PG-13",
            "Released": "01 May 2015",
            "Runtime": "141 min",
            "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
            "Director": "Joss Whedon",
            "Writer": "Joss Whedon, Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Jack Kirby (based on the Marvel comics by), Joe Simon (character created by: Captain America), Jack Kirby (character created by: Captain America), Jim Starlin (character created by: Thanos)",
            "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Evans",
            "Plot": "When Tony Stark and Bruce Banner try to jump-start a dormant peacekeeping program called Ultron, things go horribly wrong and it's up to Earth's mightiest heroes to stop the villainous Ultron from enacting his terrible plan.",
            "Language": "English, Korean",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Awards": "8 wins & 49 nominations.",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM4OGJmNWMtOTM4Ni00NTE3LTg3MDItZmQxYjc4N2JhNmUxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgzMDMzMTg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Ratings": [{
                "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
                "Value": "7.3/10"
            }, {
                "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
                "Value": "75%"
            }, {
                "Source": "Metacritic",
                "Value": "66/100"
            }],
            "Metascore": "66",
            "imdbRating": "7.3",
            "imdbVotes": "759,059",
            "imdbID": "tt2395427",
            "Type": "movie",
            "DVD": "08 Sep 2015",
            "BoxOffice": "$459,005,868",
            "Production": "Marvel Studios",
            "Website": "N/A",
            "Response": "True"
        }


    ]
}
```

my js fetch code:

```
//DOM element
let movieSlider = document.querySelector(".mainSlider") //Grid til film
let movieTitle = document.querySelector(".mainSlider__title"); //genre titel
fetch('./media/json/movies.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((movies) => {
    console.log(movies)
//   console.log(response);
//   });
// .then(movie => {
    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        const element = movies[i];
        movieSlider.innerHTML += `
        <div class="mainSlider__item" style='background:url("${element.Poster}"); background-size:cover;'>
        <div class="mainSlider__item-playButton">
            <div class="mainSlider__item-title">${element.Title}</div>
            <div class="mainSlider__item-info">${element.Year}</div>
            <div class="mainSlider__item-desc">${element.Runtime}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        `


    }
});
```

Comment: Accessing an object's values by the property name will be covered in any basic JS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the property names and also you don't need them. (They seem like categories). You can use `Object.values` and `Array.flat` methods to retrieve an array that contains just movies like below :

```
const json = `your json`
const movies = Object.values(json).flat();
console.log(movies);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const json = `your json`
const movies = Object.values(json).flat();
console.log(movies);
```

Comment: You could be more imaginative when copy/pasting someone else's answer.